# Designing a circuit that calculates Hamming distance?

Tags: decoder

I came across this question and I couldn't find it in textbooks or the internet. Seems pretty unique.

I guess there would be some comparators and adders involved, but I have no clue where to start. I'd appreciate if someone could explain in very simple, newbie proof terms.

Answer (score 6):

"the Hamming distance between two strings of equal length is the number of positions at which the corresponding symbols are different." (Wiki)

Simple approach: compare the bits pairwise using XOR (output is 1 when the inputs differ) and add the outputs of the XORs using a string of adders.

This will work, but there is probably a simpler way to add a bunch of 1's and 0's than using full adders.

I am not sure I agree with the WiKi definition, to me Hamming distance is a property of an encoding (a subset of valid values, within a larger set of possible values). An encoding (or a subset) is a mathematical construct, not a physical value, so you can't input it to a digital circuit.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to talk about the Hamming distance between two strings. When you talk about an encoding system, what you're usually interested in is the *minimum Hammng distance* between all possible pairs of strings, which is what allows you to guarantee certain properties of the encoding.

Comment: That 'minimum Hamming distance' is what I most often hear called just 'Hamming distance'. Alas, terminology is not standardized and varies between industries and countries..